# Microsoft Azure Site-to-Site VPN with Palo Alto

Tags: azure

I'm trying to build a Microsoft Azure site-to-site vpn where the local end device is a Palo Alto Networks firewall.

I have been trying to follow the example shown here ....

https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/Integration-Articles/Configuring-IKEv2-VPN-for-Microsoft-Azure-Environment/ta-p/60340

But I'm not having any luck establishing a connection.

Has anyone successfully established a connection with a Palo Alto firewall?

Kind regards

Carlton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Palo Alto is compatible, but you may have an OS version which is not compatible with RouteBased configuration.

Make sure you have a compliant appliance:

> PAN-OS 6.1.5 or later (PolicyBased)
>
> PAN-OS 7.0.5 or later (RouteBased)

If your router does not support RouteBased configuration, recreate Azure VPN Gateway as PolicyBased. That should fix the problem.

Bear in mind that PolicyBased is 1-1, i.e, you will not be able to use Azure as a VPN hub for several office branches.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/

Comment: Bruno, thanks for responding. I have the document you suggested. I was wondering if anyone had successfully configured Palo Alto as vpn to an Azure VPN

Comment: Palo Alto is compatible with both VPN models in Azure. I've successfully connected my customers to Azure through it without any issues. Please, be more specific to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Is the the following link enough to successfully setup the Palo Alto as a gateway to Azure

Comment: I don't have one now to replicate but seems to have everything you need.

Comment: Bruno, thanks again for responding. It's a pity you don't have one to replicate. Do you know where I could find a replication? Cheers

Comment: The guide you linked is very clear. Maybe your problem could be related to those people in the comments section. Did you check if any of their issues is the same you are facing?

Comment: Hi Bruno, I followed the guide in detail and IKE is up and but the tunnel is down. I'm now getting the following information. ( description contains 'IKEv2 child SA negotiation is failed as initiator, non-rekey. Failed SA: 64.187.124.5[500]-13.89.33.31[500] message id:0x00000107. Error code 111' ) . However, Microsoft Azure is showing connected. Any ideas?

Comment: Can I add images to this question?